# How can I add custom wrapper like keyword 'sout' - system.out.println in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, macros, customization

You know about this special quick wrapper, if you select sout, it will wrap System.out.println() around whatever your cursor is at.
[image: dd]

I use lots of log.d, log.wtf, is it possible to write my own command like:

'ltf' and it appears in the pop-up window above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called "Live Templates" in AS. Go to *Preferences* in AS and type there "live" or navigate to *Editor - Live Templates*. There is a button with "plus" icon on it in the top right corner. Press it to add a new template.

Some Android logger templates are already there, like *logd*, *loge* etc. They are expanded by "Tab" key by default.

Comment: perfect, i found actual Log.wtf , and just changed it to mine:Log.wtf("x",  "$content$");